# Remplazar palabras completas (casi iguales) en Java

Tags: java

Ando escribiendo un programa y necesito reemplazar algunas palabras por otras, pero a veces las palabras pueden ser similares.

Las palabras no tienen espacios, y siempre son palabras completas.

Ejemplo:

```
String[] palabrasAcambiar = {"pan","pan2"};
String[] valores = {"pan1","pan2"};
String oracion = "el pan es mejor que el pan2";

//REEMPLAZAR PALABRAS POR VALORES
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    oracion = oracion.replace(palabrasAcambiar[i],valores[i]);  
}
//resultado: el pan1 es mejor que el pan12
//resultado deseado:  el pan1 es mejor que el pan2
```

Ya sé que cambio el "pan" de el "pan2" por "pan1" y resultó el "pan12" <- lol

Bueno.. quería saber si alguien sabe cómo lidiar con este problema?

Comment: Hola mariano, ya intente eso da el mismo resultado, si es util para muchas ocaciones, pero por ejemplo para este ejemplo, no es util

Comment: ¿Siempre se reemplazan palabras completas?

Comment: Si, las palabras no tienen espacios, siempre son palabras completas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre y cuando se trate de **palabras** (formadas por letras, números o guión bajo) **completas** (no tienen letras, números o guiones bajos antes o después), utilizando expresiones regulares, se puede usar el límite de palabra completa [`\b`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds). Además, usamos [Pattern.quote()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) para escapar cualquier metacaracter que podría estar en las palabras buscadas.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
```

```java
String[] palabras = {"pan","pan2"};
String[] valores = {"pan1","pan2"};
String oracion = "el pan es mejor que el pan2";

//REEMPLAZAR PALABRAS POR VALORES
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    oracion = oracion.replaceAll("\\b"+Pattern.quote(palabras[i])+"\\b",valores[i]);  
}

System.out.println(oracion);
```

**Resultado:**

```
el pan1 es mejor que el pan2
```

<kbd>[Demo en Ideone](http://ideone.com/CUHQrK)</kbd>

Comment: Lo intente y funciona muy bien, pero no entendi cuando es que no lo puedo usar?

Comment: por ejemplo en mi programa las palabras serian limitadas a letras y numeros, pero lo que pongan antes o despues de las palabras depende de el usuario puede ser un espacio un simbolo(+,*,/) pero jamas otra letra junta

Comment: Sólo en el caso de que no sea una palabra completa. Intenté definir "palabra completa" como pude. Por ejemplo, no reemplazará ninguna de los siguientes: `_pan2_`, `aapan2`, `pan22`, y **sí** reemplazará: `¡pan2!`, `-pan2?`, `(pan2)`. El caso del guión bajo es especial, ya que lo considera como parte de una palabra, pero es el único.

Comment: Muchas gracias! creo esta es la solucción para mi programa. gracias